# What is the difference between a design pattern and an STL library component such as map in c++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stl

im currently prepping for my exam and our professor gave us this example question that may come up and Im not sure how to answear it. Thankyou :)

"What is the difference between a design pattern and an STL library component such as map?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between design patterns and libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256753/what-is-the-difference-between-design-patterns-and-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

A design pattern is a way whereas STL is s collection of tools (mechanisms). Some problems are Common to Software development (encountered frequently by many developers). So, the solution to those problems is called a Design pattern. Those solutions are called patterns and used as it is where they are required.  Whereas, STL is a library which will provide inbuilt tools (like vector, pair, map) to use them in your program. There is no any relation between Design pattern and STL in C++ (or there might be if you implement STL in implementation of design pattern).

For example. Singleton design pattern restricts class to have only 1 object (like you want to use DB from multiple remote locations but you want only a single channel to shared for DB connection). So, we can use a private constructor to implement that. We can use static variables which will count objects of the class and static function to return the address of the object to the pointer of the class.

Whereas, the map is just like a data structure where you can store values in <key, value> pair. Further, the vector is simply array but without memory restriction (like every time you insert a new value in that, vector capacity is doubled from its original capacity memory is allocated dynamically in internal implementation (there is a difference between vector size and capacity)).

Comment: Blueprint over "way" might be a bit clearer. More like a blueprint template. I'm obviously nit-picking as you go on to explain the differences more clearly.